# Is there a startup file (like .bashrc) for i3 where i can set environmet variables?

Tags: environment-variables

It would help me to setup my system-wide proxy. I'm using latest Ubuntu and tried `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession`,

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://....
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [i3 uses `sh`](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_i3bar_command) to launch stuff, and does not source `$PATH` from `~/.bashrc` :

```
cat ~/.xsession-errors
(...)
/bin/sh: 1: mycommand: not found
```

So, just create a `~/.xsessionrc` file and put your statements in it :

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://....
```

Then logout and back in ; It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

System-wide environment can be setup by placing a script in /etc/profile.d/
For example, you may create /etc/profile.d/proxy with your

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http:// # enter your proxy settings here
```

Then chmod +x this file, then reboot :

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/proxy
systemctl reboot
```

After reopening your session you could check the variables are there :

```
env | grep HTTP
```

You should see the variables set with the values you entered in the profile script.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set system wide proxy settings you can add the following:

```
    export http_proxy='http://172.27.100.5:4444/'
    export https_proxy='http://172.27.100.5:4444/'
    export ftp_proxy='http://172.27.100.5:4444/'
    export no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
```

to your `bash.bashrc` file which is located in `/etc` folder. Of course, you should replace addresses with your ones. It works at least for Debian.